# What hex color code is "Google Plus Red"?

Tags: colors, hex, google-plus

Does anybody know what the exact hexadecimal code is for the red used in google plus icons?

Comment: #D84B37  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorpicker/   Also, off topic for SO

Comment: http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking what color an icon is, which really is not a programming-related question.

Comment: Hex - #DD4B39, RGB - (221,75,57)
http://www.designerslib.com/google-plus-color-palette-hex-rgb-colour-codes/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Google's branding guidelines show it to be #dd4b39

https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines

Comment: The link no longer says so. But if one examines the color of the G+ logo on the generated button ([developers.google.com/+/web/share](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/)), the sought-after color is `#db4437`. (FWIW I don't see a visual difference...)

Answer (score 6):

My Gimp says the color is #dd4b39

[image]

Answer (score -3):

#d34836

[Color Palette](http://designpieces.com/2012/12/google-plus-colour-palette/)

Next time maybe try Google?